# c++ designing a library / sdk, passing data between user and library

Tags: c++, interface, sdk

I'm currently designing a library which exposes code written in c++. This library will be distributed as dll or dylibs and should only expose wrapper code.

I found out that using STL functionality is not advised because it tends to cause issues if the user has a different version of the STL library (or is using different compiler settings)

So I'm moving to a more c-style interface, however there are some thing I'd like to avoid.

First, conceptually the exposed code generally has the form of

```cpp
class Functionality
{
    private:
        //constructors
    public:
        //factory methods

    public:
        void FunctionalityMethod1();
        ...

    private:
        class InternalFunctionality;
        std::unique_ptr<InternalFunctionality> mAccessor;
}
```

here `InternalFunctionality` would contain another pointer to an existing class which should not be visible in the library but actually implements the required functionality.

So I would assume that the usage of `std::unique_ptr` is generaly unsafe here. however how can I get similar functionality without having to implement an copy and move constructor ( and copy and move assign operator ) if I where to use just raw pointers. ( perhaps a different design altogether ).

Secondly, I need to sometimes take in or return a list of items. These usually are either simple types or pointer / smart pointers. Is there a way to avoid having to repeatedly to copy data.

As in the user is likely using `std::vector` on there and which is would then be converted to a raw pointer ( probably using `.data()` so no copy ) which would then be passed through to the library which would then need to be copied to a new vector.

This would also occur when an internal functions returns a vector, as returning `.data()` from a stack managed vector would not work.

( Side note most internal code used `std::vector` so `std::span` isn't an option )

Finally, sometimes a callback is needed. How can this be done such that the callback can have a closure. Would the following work.

```cpp
class CallBack1
{
    virtual void Call() = 0;
    virtual ~CallBack1() = 0;
}
```

**Summary**

1. How do I keep a link to an internal class (non exposed) without complicated memory management or repeated code.
2. How can I efficiently pass Lists between user code, the interface and internal code.
3. Callbacks with closures

Comment: I don't think there is any way other than either: (a) use a pure `C` interface or (b) distribute the source and require the end-user to compile the library locally with their tool-chain (eg Boost).

Comment: I feared as much, for issues 1 and 2 I can see how ( struct with pointer and struct with pointer and size ). but how can you pass a callback with a closure through a C interface. I would assume it has to use a function pointer. @RichardCritten

Comment: The callback should take a c-function pointer and a `void*`.  The void* call back parameter points to your internal implementation object.